# How to get comma separated values from blazor wrapper for Apexchart

Tags: c#, blazor, currency, blazor-webassembly, apexcharts

I have used ApexChart to create a simple chart. Following you can see a screenshot of it
[image]

my apex chart component razor file is this.

```
    <ApexChart @ref=_detailsChart TItem="ActualVsBudgetedIncomeResponse"
                              Title="ACTUAL VS BUDGETED INCOME"
                              Debug>

                                  <ApexPointSeries TItem="ActualVsBudgetedIncomeResponse"
                                                   Items="response_for_actual_vs_budgeted_income_Response"
                                                   Name="Actual Income"
                                                   SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar" 
                                                   XValue="@(e => e.YYYY_MM)"
                                                   YValue="@(e => Convert.ToDecimal(e.Income))"
                                                   OrderByDescending="e=>e.X"/>

                                  <ApexPointSeries TItem="ActualVsBudgetedIncomeResponse"
                                                   Items="response_for_actual_vs_budgeted_income_Response"
                                                   Name="Budgeted Income"
                                                   SeriesType="SeriesType.Bar" 
                                                   XValue="@(e => e.YYYY_MM)"
                                                   YValue="@(e => Convert.ToDecimal(e.BgtIncome))"
                                                   OrderByDescending="e=>e.X"/>

 </ApexChart>
```

in the above figure, you can see that the actual income values are not comma-separated values. these values are very hard to read sometimes. budgeted incomes are behaving like this.

let's consider the Actual-Income value,
this `YValue="@(e => Convert.ToDecimal(e.Income))"` line is responsible to get actual income values. I am getting this income as **double** type from the database. So I have to convert it to **decimal** type to include here.

My final requirement is however **getting comma-separated value** for this Actual income and Budgeted income (as an example I should get **29,321,000** for the marked value on the above chart). how can I do this??, please help me. appreciate all your answers.

Comment: Have you tried using the [Formatter options](https://apexcharts.github.io/Blazor-ApexCharts/features/formatters) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass some javascript as a formatter, something like this.

```
options.Yaxis.Add(new YAxis
        {
            Labels = new AxisLabels
            {
                Formatter = @"function (value) {
                return '$' + Number(value).toLocaleString();}"
            }
        }
    );
```

If you are using webassembly you also have the option to use .net as a formatter, Using the FormatYAxisLabel

```
   <ApexChart TItem="Order"
           Title="Order Net Value"
           FormatYAxisLabel="GetYAxisLabel">


private string GetYAxisLabel(decimal value)
{
    return "$" + value.ToString("N0");
}
```

Details https://apexcharts.github.io/Blazor-ApexCharts/features/formatters